# How to calculate number of years between two dates in different pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

One column has dates but the other has a string containing a date, so I first need to extract the date part from that string.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

# the dataframe - id column always starts with year, month and day
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['19520630F8', '19680321A5', '19711113E2'],
                   'dte': ['2010-06-02', '2007-08-12', '2013-01-23']})

# create a date string from df['id'] to the format yyyy-mm-dd
dob = (df['id'].str[:4] + '-' +
       df['id'].str[4:6] + '-' +
       df['id'].str[6:8])

# calculate age (years only) at df['dte']
df['age'] = relativedelta(date, dob).years
```

I get the error message:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I don't understand the ambiguousness of my data, and where to apply those empty/bool/item...
The `df['dta']` column if of object data type and not datetime, but wrapping the creation of dob in `pd.to_datetime` wont help.

EDIT
The expected output should be

```
          dte          id  age
0  2010-06-02  19520630F8   57
1  2007-08-12  19680321A5   39
2  2013-01-23  19711113E2   41
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe need:

```
df['age'] = (np.floor((pd.to_datetime(df['dte']) - 
             pd.to_datetime(dob)).dt.days / 365.25)).astype(int)
print (df)
           id         dte  age
0  19520630F8  2010-06-02   57
1  19680321A5  2007-08-12   39
2  19711113E2  2013-01-23   41
```

**Details**:

Convert columns to datetimes and subtract:

```
print (pd.to_datetime(df['dte']) -  pd.to_datetime(dob))
0   21156 days
1   14388 days
2   15047 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Convert to days and then to years:

```
print ((pd.to_datetime(df['dte']) -  pd.to_datetime(dob)).dt.days / 365.25)
0    57.921971
1    39.392197
2    41.196441
dtype: float64
```

Last `floor` values by [`numpy.floor.`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.floor.html):

```
print ((np.floor((pd.to_datetime(df['dte']) - pd.to_datetime(dob)).dt.days / 365.25)))
0    57.0
1    39.0
2    41.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank's alot! That worked, but I realized I need the real age, not just the difference between the years

Comment: @leofer - Changed solution by your expected output.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one solution using `dateutil.relativedelta` and a list comprehension. The important point is to ensure you have two `datetime` series before you use them in computations.

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

df['id_dte'] = pd.to_datetime(df['id'].str[:8], format='%Y%m%d')
df['dte'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dte'])

df['age'] = [relativedelta(a, b).years for a, b in zip(df['dte'], df['id_dte'])]

print(df)

         dte          id     id_dte  age
0 2010-06-02  19520630F8 1952-06-30   57
1 2007-08-12  19680321A5 1968-03-21   39
2 2013-01-23  19711113E2 1971-11-13   41
```

If, however, you just want to take the difference between the years (*not* derived from the age), you can just use `datetime` attributes directly:

```
df['age'] = df['dte'].dt.year - df['id_dte'].dt.year

print(df)

         dte          id     id_dte  age
0 2010-06-02  19520630F8 1952-06-30   58
1 2007-08-12  19680321A5 1968-03-21   39
2 2013-01-23  19711113E2 1971-11-13   42
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! But why do you create a new column df['id_dte']? df['id'] = pd.to_datetime(df['id'].str[:8], format='%Y%m%d') seems to work.

Comment: @leofer, Because you may want to use it later, and for clarity. You can omit it altogether, like `df['age'] = df['dte'].dt.year - pd.to_datetime(df['id'].str[:8], format='%Y%m%d').dt.year`. But that's an unreadable mess.

Answer (score 1):

Dividing by 365.25 will present problem when dte and id have the same month/day.

A solution would be subtract the years, and then subtract 1 from the result if month/day of dte is lesser than month/day of id.

```py
df['age'] = df['dte'].dt.year - df['id_dte'].dt.year

df['age'] -= ((df['dte'].dt.month * 32 + df['dte'].dt.day) - (df['id_dte'].dt.month * 32 + df['id_dte'].dt.day)).apply(lambda x: 1 if x < 0 else 0)
```